# Usuário logando em outras contas

Tags: php, session, login

Olá, venho em meio desta porque já não sei mais o que fazer com esse problema que está me assombrando a dias!
Ontem praticamente do nada (sério, do nada mesmo) iniciou este problema, onde ao usuário logar em seu usuário normalmente e desse um "F5" na página, estaria na conta de outro usuário aleatório. De início e ainda tenho essa teoria, acho que é uma espécie de "Cache", mas não tenho nenhum cache ativado em meu site, nem no "Sucuri" (Firewall o qual uso) e nem mesmo em minha CMS tem alguma estrutura de Cache.

Por isso este problema está me fazendo ficar louco já, pois não sei o que pode ser e nem muito menos a fonte. Deixo com vocês o código de "Log in" para vocês verem que eu (pelo menos acho) não estou fazendo nada incorretamente.

AuthController.php -

```
public function login()
{
    global $twig, $params, $language;
    try {

        $user = Model\User::select()
                            ->where('username', QB::EQ, $_POST['login_username'])
                            ->whereOr('email', QB::EQ, $_POST['login_username'])->find();

        if($user->login($_POST['login_password'])) {

            if($user->isBanned()) {
                radCMS\App::Message('error', $language['home']['notifications']['banned'], [
                    '{username}' => $user->getUsername(),
                    '{reason}' => $user->getBan()->getReason(),
                    '{expires}' => date('d-m-Y \à\s H:i:s', $user->getBan()->getExpire())
                    ]);
                return radCMS\App::Redirect('home');
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id();

                $user->setLast_ip(OctaCMS\App::GetIP());
                $user->setLast_online(time());

                radCMS\App::Redirect('me');
                radCMS\App::Message('success', $language['notifications']['logged_in']);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            radCMS\App::Message('error',  $language['home']['notifications']['login_incorrect']);
            Model\Input::saveFields($_POST);
            radCMS\App::Redirect('home');
        }

    } catch (\RangeException $ex) {
        radCMS\App::Message('error',  $language['home']['notifications']['login_incorrect']);
        radCMS\App::Redirect('home');
```

---

Sendo que eu trabalho com MVC, eu tenho isto em meu index.php

index.php -

```
if(!session_start()) 
    session_start();
```

---

E outro arquivo eu possuo uma pequena função o qual apenas verifica se o usuário está logado

App.php -

```
public static function isLoggedIn() 
{
    return isset($_SESSION['id']);
}
```

Então galera, apreciaria muito uma ajuda nisso.

Comment: Que framework é este?

Comment: A `$_SESSION['id']` é o id do usuário?

Comment: Acho que você precisa postar uma parte do model do user também. Pois as informações do controller pelo que eu estou vendo não é o problema. O problema pode estar dentro no model ou  no controller, aonde faz a seleção do usuário.